# Sorting object with multiple conditions and unknown keys using lodash

Tags: javascript, sorting, lodash

I've got an object with dynamic keys that I need to sort by values and if there's a tie between values, use the key to sort in alphabetical order.

Example Input:

```
   const unsortedObj = { 
      "a": 2, 
      "b": 3, 
      "c" : 2 
    }
```

Expected Output:

```
   const sortedOutput = {
    "b": 3,
    "a": 2,
    "c": 2
   }
```

So far I've got this lodash chaining to at least sort by the values but can't figure out how to apply the second/alphabeutical condition when there's a tie:

```
    const sortedObj = _.fromPairs(
        _.sortBy(_.toPairs(unsortedObj), 1).reverse()
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For complex sorts you should use `_.orderBy()`.

Set the iteratees (2nd param) to the indexes you want to sort by (`[1, 0]`) - sort by index 1 first, and if there's a tie by index 0.

Set the `orders` (3rd param) to be the way in which you want to sort each index (`[desc, asc]`) - sort descending by index 1, but ascending by index 0.

```js
const unsortedObj = {
  "a": 2,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 2
}

const sortedObj = _.fromPairs(
  _.orderBy(
    _.toPairs(unsortedObj),
    [1, 0],
    ['desc', 'asc']
  )
);

console.log(sortedObj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js" integrity="sha512-WFN04846sdKMIP5LKNphMaWzU7YpMyCU245etK3g/2ARYbPK9Ub18eG+ljU96qKRCWh+quCY7yefSmlkQw1ANQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

With lodash/fp you can create a reusable and readable function using `_.flow()`:

```js
const fn = _.flow(
  _.toPairs,
  _.orderBy([1, 0], ['desc', 'asc']),
  _.fromPairs
)

const unsortedObj = {
  "a": 2,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 2
}

const sortedObj = fn(unsortedObj);

console.log(sortedObj)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```